# update table by removing common word

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite

I have an database in that  "[proper n.]" word is common

looking like

[image]

i want to remove " [proper n.]" word from col 2 by updating it

can any body help me how to resolve this issue in using sqlite3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oracle you can use `REPLACE` function to replace a string. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) for more in detail.

Try like this,

```
UPDATE table 
SET    col2 = REPLACE(col2, ' [proper n.]', '');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
UPDATE tablename set COL_2 = REPLACE(COL_2, ' [proper n.]', '') 
WHERE COL_2 like '% [proper n.]%'
```